# why BytesWritable.setSize(size) make the space of bytes to 1.5*size?

Tags: hadoop

I am writing the program using hadoop. my question code is as belows(the code is in mapper):

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[2];
tmp[0] = 0x01;
tmp[1] = 0x02;
BytesWritable outputKey = new BytesWritable();
outputKey.set(tmp, 0, 2);
```

However, when I operate the key in reducer which I got from the mapper, it made me a surprise:

```
byte[] reducerKey = key.getBytes();
```

The reducerKey is as belows:

```
reducerKey[0] -> 0x01;
reducerKey[1] -> 0x02;
reducerKey[2] -> 0x00;
```

why the tmp which I input is 2 bytes of length, but when I got, it become 3 bytes of length.

Then I read the source code of BytesWritable.setSize(size), 
I found this:

```
public void setSize(int size) {
 if (size > getCapacity()) {
  setCapacity(size * 3 / 2);
 }
this.size = size;}
```

So when the bytes into the BytesWritable, why the data structure create a 1.5*size space for byte[]? I think it's a waste of space, because the 0.5 * size space is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common programming practice to amortize the cost of [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) resizes.

Now why it isn't an issue, and a good default behavior, for Hadoop writables ?

1. Writable objects are usually singletons since they can be, and are, reused. You usually want to size them to fit your largest buffer. Creating a new Writable each time, waste time and can put pressure on the GC. It makes sense to make them a little larger than the largest already used buffer.
2. If you want to avoid the extra room you can use the [BytesWritable(byte[] bytes)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.java#52) constructor  or [setCapacity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.java#117). Please note that the constructor is much more efficient than `set()` since it does not have to copy  the data. Only two references have to be set.